# Как сравнить 2 переменные: php и js (AngularJS)

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs

У меня есть такой код:

```
<div ng-init="users = [
        <?foreach($users as $user):?>
        {id:'<?= $user['id'] ?>', name:'<?= $user['name'] ?>', phone:'<?= $user['phone'] ?>', country_id:'<?= $user['country_id'] ?>'},
        <?endforeach;?>
]"></div>
<div class="row" ng-controller="AngularCtrl" ng-repeat="user in users">
```

Тут я делаю что-то с user.
А потом мне нужно использовать список стран и сравнить user.country_id c $country['id'].

```
    <select class="form-control" name="country" onchange="setCountry(user.id, this.value)" ng-disabled="!country">
        <?foreach ($countries as $country):?>
        <option value="<?= $country['id'] ?>" <?if ($user['country_id'] == $country['id']) echo "selected"?>><?= $country['country'] ?></option>
        <?endforeach;?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Как это можно сделать? Или как соответственно переписать код?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, в чем именно проблема. А в чем вас не устраивет ваш код?

Comment: Я заменил foreach на ng-repeat, и теперь у меня нет php-переменной $user['country_id'], но есть user.country_id.

Comment: Давайте сначала определимся с тем, что js и php непосредственно не взаимодействуют друг с другом. Взаимодействие происходит по http. То есть php присылает какие то данные, а дальше js с ними работает. Если на клиенте нужны новые данные с сервера, то делается еще один запрос.

Comment: Если я заполню массив стран также, как массив пользователей, то какое соответствующее выражение или условие, типа "<?if ($user['country_id'] == $country['id']) echo "selected"?>", мне нужно будет написать?

Comment: А чем foreach вас не устраивает?

Comment: dchayka, мне нужен был ng-repeat, из-за чего я лишился $user['country_id'].

Comment: Что бы небыло такой путаницы, научитесь делать ajax запросы. https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07